# How would you generate a new array column over a window?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to generate a new column that is an array over a window however it appears that the array function does not work over a window and I'm struggling to find an alternative method.

Code snippet:

```
df = df.withColumn('array_output', F.array(df.things_to_agg_in_array).over(Window.partitionBy("aggregate_over_this")))
```

Ideally what I'd like is an output that looks like the following table:

```html
+---------------------+------------------------+--------------+
| Aggregate Over This | Things to Agg in Array | Array Output |
+---------------------+------------------------+--------------+
| 1                   | C                      | [C,F,K,L]    |
+---------------------+------------------------+--------------+
| 1                   | F                      | [C,F,K,L]    |
+---------------------+------------------------+--------------+
| 1                   | K                      | [C,F,K,L]    |
+---------------------+------------------------+--------------+
| 1                   | L                      | [C,F,K,L]    |
+---------------------+------------------------+--------------+
| 2                   | A                      | [A,B,C]      |
+---------------------+------------------------+--------------+
| 2                   | B                      | [A,B,C]      |
+---------------------+------------------------+--------------+
| 2                   | C                      |    [A,B,C]   |
+---------------------+------------------------+--------------+
```

For further context this is part of an explode which will then be rejoined onto another table based on the 'aggregate over this' and as a result only returning one instance of `array_ouput`.

Thanks

Comment: Annoyingly i think i've found an answer which is to use F.collect_list instead. However, if anyone has a more efficient answer that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution used `collect_list()`, not sure if it fulfills your requirement.

```
myValues = [(1,'C'),(1,'F'),(1,'K'),(1,'L'),(2,'A'),(2,'B'),(2,'C')]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(myValues,['Aggregate_Over_This','Things_to_Agg_in_Array'])
df.show()
+-------------------+----------------------+
|Aggregate_Over_This|Things_to_Agg_in_Array|
+-------------------+----------------------+
|                  1|                     C|
|                  1|                     F|
|                  1|                     K|
|                  1|                     L|
|                  2|                     A|
|                  2|                     B|
|                  2|                     C|
+-------------------+----------------------+
df.registerTempTable('table_view')
df1=sqlContext.sql(
    'select Aggregate_Over_This, Things_to_Agg_in_Array, collect_list(Things_to_Agg_in_Array) over (partition by Aggregate_Over_This) as aray_output from table_view'
)
df1.show()
+-------------------+----------------------+------------+
|Aggregate_Over_This|Things_to_Agg_in_Array| aray_output|
+-------------------+----------------------+------------+
|                  1|                     C|[C, F, K, L]|
|                  1|                     F|[C, F, K, L]|
|                  1|                     K|[C, F, K, L]|
|                  1|                     L|[C, F, K, L]|
|                  2|                     A|   [A, B, C]|
|                  2|                     B|   [A, B, C]|
|                  2|                     C|   [A, B, C]|
+-------------------+----------------------+------------+
```